# How to reduce the size of captions in all figures

Tags: latex

I want the captions of my figures and table to have the same size as \footnotesize. Is there something to put in the preambule of my document to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to set the `font` key-value to `footnotesize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\begin{document}

Some regular text set in \verb|\normalsize|.
\begin{table}[t]
  \caption{A table using \texttt{\string\footnotesize}.}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{A figure using \texttt{\string\footnotesize}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It is also possible to adjust the label and text formats individually for `figure`s and `table`s separately. However, consistency is a better option here.

Comment: how do you set to a pt number?

Comment: @ZachSmith: Define your own caption font using `\DeclareCaptionFont`. See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/Eg42HRWQ).